# Basic Window.alert function not working in Meteor

Tags: javascript, events, dom, meteor

Hi I have a basic function I'm trying to get to to work. Please let me know any reasons you see that this is broken.

```
'click #addTag': function(event, template) {
var tagTitle = template.find("#AddVideoTags").value;
window.alert(tagTitle);
}
```

Comment: is it a typo ? `#AddVideoTags` should be `#addVideoTags` ?

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that template.find("#AddVideoTags") is undefined, which throws an error when you try to access the .value.  I reproduced this in some dummy code:

```
'click #addTag': function(event, template) {
    window.alert('This will work');
    var tagTitle = template.find("#ThisDoesNotExist").value; // This throws an exception.
    window.alert(tagTitle); // This will not execute.
}
```